# Jenkins/Hudson and Gallio Unit-Testing Integration

Tags: unit-testing, hudson, gallio

I am struggling to get it to run my tests. In the Execute Windows batch command on Jenkins, I have put the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe" /report-type:Html /verbosity:quiet “Project.Tests\bin\Release\*.Tests.dll
```

It doesn't like the `*.Tests.dll` bit, in that it says:

Cannot find directory containing file pattern `Project.Tests\bin\Release\*.Tests.dll`.

My next question would be if I change the report-type to xml, is it straight forward to get my unit test reports published in hudson?

many thanks.

Comment: Gallio.Echo supports file patterns with wildcards. So basically it should work. Are you sure that the specified path is relative to the current working directory?

Comment: Thank you @Yann Trevin, yes the path is relative to the workspace directory. I couldn't find out what the heck was happening. Turns out it was a combination of things. I had to elevate the account the Jenkins service runs at, and there was a funny '"' character from copying the command from the command window and pasting it into the Jenkins batch window...

Answer (score 4):

The following extract runs Gallio tests in a Windows Batch command build step [(Download Gallio from)](http://www.gallio.org/Downloads.aspx)

```
"c:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe" %WORKSPACE%\YourTestPro\bin\Debug\YourTestPro.dll /report-directory:%WORKSPACE%\TestResults /report-type:Xml /working-directory:%WORKSPACE%
```

To setup Jenkins report generation

1. Add the Gallio Jenkins plugin to your Jenkins installation to publish the report
2. In your project under the *Add post project action* build steps add the xUnit test result report
3. Select the Add button that appears in the xUnit action step
4. Select Gallio - N/A
5. Add **TestResults/*.xml** to the *Gallio N/A Pattern*

Answer (score 2):

You can use Maven plugin for .Net: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/.Net+plugin 
It takes care of Gallio command line generation: you can provide a filter :

```
<visual.test.project.pattern>*.Tests</visual.test.project.pattern>
<gallio.filter>Category:UnitTests</gallio.filter>
```

Then, the Maven plugin generates the command line.
You also have a lot of advantages using maven: integration with Partcover/NCover, stylecop/fxcop/gendarme, etc.

OR you can make a MSBuild script for that:

```
<itemGroup>
    <TestsDll Include="**\bin\$(Configuration)\*.Tests.dll" />
</itemGroup>
<Exec Command="Gallio.Echo.exe @(TestsDll, ' ')"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure you want to look into using the [Gallio Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gallio+Plugin) instead of using the execute windows batch command.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on Gallio plugin. Observing it, I don't see any xml test results being generated. It looks like it only transforms the xml document where I tell it to look. I've told it to look at 'Reports\*.xml'

@Joel, if you could perhaps share what you have in your 'Publish testing tools result report' command, you could thankfully prove me wrong?

Comment: @Eryn I'm sorry that I'm not working on a project using Hudson at this time, so I don't have an example for you. The Gallio Plugin extends the [xUnit Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin), some documentation there might help. Also, you might want 'Reports/*.xml' not 'Reports*.xml'